# ¿Como conectarme con SQLALCHEMY a una basededatos?

Tags: mysql, python, base-de-datos, sqlalchemy

Estoy haciendo un test en Python para comprobar que la base de datos de una máquina está activa.

Mi problema es que al conectarme me da el error:

> "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'david'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")"

y mi código es:

```
    connection = 'sqlite:///'+user+':'+password+'@'+str(host)+':'+str(port)+"/"+dbname
    self.engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection) #Establish connection
    self.connection = self.engine.connect()
    print('Connected to '+connection)
    result = self.connection.execute('SELECT COUNT(name) FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%pdf"')
```

Yo en 'user' no tengo definido "david", tal y como aparece en el error y como veis si que utilizo password.

Comment: En principio, aparentemente, está bien, puede ser un tema de permisos. Comprueba que la cadena de conexión es correcta, que usas el driver adecuado, y que puedes conectarte con esos mismos datos mediante otros medios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según las etiquetas que has usado veo que quieres conectarte a una base de datos mysql, pero en tu código utilizas el driver de sqlite(esta solo tiene usuario y dirección). Tienes que usar el driver de mysql:

Aqui un ejemplo:

```
from sqlalchemy import *

engine = create_engine('mysql://'+user+':'+password+'@+str(host)+'/'++dbname+'?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0', pool_recycle=port)

connection = engine.connect()
```

Comment: Gracias! Funcionó

Answer (score 0):

No especificaste si estás usando un SGBD MySQL o SQLlite.

Si quieres conectarte a una base de datos **MySQl** te recomiendo usar `pymysql`, ahora mismo estoy usándola para un proyecto y después de probar varias librerías esta es la que mejor me ha funcionado.

Se instala usando `pip install pymysql`.
Aquí te dejo un código de ejemplo de su uso y verás que es bastante simple y te servirá para comprobar que la bd esté activa:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', db='tweetsjun2016', charset = 'utf8mb4')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(""" 
            SELECT * FROM 20160607_tweets
            WHERE 20160607_tweets.creation_date >= '2016-06-07 10:51'
            LIMIT 5
            """)

for row in cur:
    print(row) # Lista records o tuplas
```

Basicamente si ejecuta el statement `pymysql.connect`sin lanzar un error, significa que conectaste correctamente.
Yo haría algo así para el test:

```
import pymysql
try:
 conn = pymysql.connect(host=str(host), port=port, user='user', passwd=password, db=dbname, charset = 'utf8mb4')
except pymysql.err.OperationalError:
 print("Error conectando con la base de datos.")
```